# CSS/ HTML Empty Space issue with Div alignment

Tags: html, css, alignment

i have a Commercial Website Called [Akaratak](https://akaratak.com)

 In the [Search Page](https://akaratak.com/Search) in Mobile mode (after resizing the browser to the minimum)

 there is a space left empty between some divs
as follows:
[image]
i know it must be a simple question but i couldn't get it to get aligned

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

As i can see you are using Bootstrap, but not in a proper way. You should change your layout to a 4 or 6 column one so the grid will auto adjust to a 2x2 layout as you want it.

Another thing that you can do is to make your layour like:

2x2

-1-

2x2

Using bootstrap classes you just need to add one class to the third object of each row making it sm-12 and the others sm-6. I suggest you to read more carefully [Bootstrap grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) to use it the right way.

Instead you can use [Bootstrap 4 grid system](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/) witch allow you to move and workaround your problem in a nice way.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the `<div class="clearfix"></div>` child on every `<div class="deal-top-top"></div>` parent :)